# How to disable fetching git repository by gitlab runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

There is such task in my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
deploy_all:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cp project/target/jnlp/* html/jnlp/
  tags:
    - client:deploy-all
```

Everything works fine except unnecessary git repository fetching. Below is extract from runner's log

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.1.0 (0118d89)
...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 8dfc104 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
...
Job succeeded
```

The repository is not needed here because I need only artifacts from other tasks. Is it possible to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution:

- upgraded gitlab to version 10.x, manual is here https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html
- disabled git checkout in the build script (by adding variables)

  ```
  deploy_all:
    variables:
      GIT_STRATEGY: none
      GIT_CHECKOUT: "false"
    stage: deploy
    script:
      - cp project/target/jnlp/* html/jnlp/
    tags:
      - client:deploy-all
  ```